# Real metrics on Productivity differences between nodejs and asp.net in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, node.js, nosql

I am NOT looking for opinions. I HAVE Googled this.

I want to know if anyone is aware of any reliable benchmarks by a credible source or academic studies that show a productivity difference between developing a web server back end in node.js vs. asp.net C#.

I will throw into the mix Functional vs.Object Oriented Programming. And, also NoSQL Document storage vs. Relational storage.

Comment: I can't imagine an actual metric exists. The time relies solely on the developers themselves. For instance, are they experienced in framework `x`? Do they actually manage their time properly? The technology is just a tool. I can swing a hammer, but I am not a carpenter. A skilled carpenter would be able to produce something better and faster with a rock instead of me and my hammer.

Comment: Productivity benchmark would be biased anyway. You should find a developer with a good level of experience on both platform, but how would you ensure that ?

Comment: I get your points. It seems like something that could be studied. If you took 2 teams of the exact same size - large teams - and the exact same number of years experience in their respective platforms, gave them the same set of application requirements and set them loose, I think you could reasonably measure a difference. Clearly, no one has done that yet. Thanks for the comments.